# This question is for the Jehovah's Witnesses, how can Jesus Christ be Michael the archangel in view of Hebrews 2:14-16?

Tags: christology, jehovahs-witnesses, angels, hebrews, michael

Hebrews 2:14-16,

> "Since then the children share in flesh and blood, He/Jesus Christ Himself likewise also partook of the same, that through death He might render powerless him who had the power of death, that is the devil; vs15, and might deliver those who through fear of death were subject to slavery all their lives. Vs16, For assuredly He does not give help to angels, but He gives help to the descendants of Abraham."

The word "partook" in vs14 means, "to take or have a part or share alone with others." In other words, Jesus Christ partook in becoming a man. He did not partake in becoming an angel, specifically Michael the archangel.

The redemptive work of Jesus Christ was not done for angels but for mankind. The author of Hebrews pointed out that the Son identified himself not with angels but with the nation of Israel, the descendants of Abraham and for those who have faith.
Hebrews 2:16.

Moreover, since the Witnesses teach that Jesus Christ is a created man he cannot at the same time and "ontologically" be a created angel named Michael. In fact, God the Father says of His Son at Hebrews 1:6,

> "And again when He brings the first-born into the world, He says, And let all the angels of God worship Him."

How do Jehovah's Witnesses resolve these contradictions?